# How to get facebook page posts without using facebook api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a simple webpage that will just display the most recent, let's say 5, posts from a certain facebook page. I have tried so many ways to use the Facebook API, but no matter what I do, it either returns nothing, or I get an access denied message. I am an admin of the page.

What is the best way to do this with PHP? If there is no other way to get facebook posts, what is the best way to use the API?

I would also like to get the post URL, not the contents of the post.

Comment: Check this out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

Comment: I have tried file_get_contents, and tried using curl. file_get_contents returns permission denied. curl does not output anything.

Comment: Then you should be researching how to find out what the actual cause of the error was in such cases by now, right? The response body usually contains error information in human readable form - so go read up on how to get access to that using either file_get_contents or curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way using zapier.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get either the user/page access token. Then, you will be able to get the last 5 posts using: [https://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR_PAGE_ID}/posts?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}&limit=5](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BYOUR_PAGE_ID%7D/posts?access_token=%7BYOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN%7D&limit=5)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I get the response with PHP? file_get_contents and curl both do not work.